# Only one Get works in my API

Tags: asp.net, rest, get, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have two gets:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/users")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetSpecificUser(int id)
    {
        var foundUser = Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.ID == id);

        return Json(foundUser).ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/users")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAllUsers()
    {
        return Json(Users).ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;
    }
```

Only the GetAllUsers seems to work. (accessing by http://localhost:61800/api/users)

Attempting to access GetSpecificUser by http://localhost:61800/api/users/1

I put breakpoints in both methods yet only the GetAllUsers gets hit.

I am using the default RouteConfig

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the specific Get work?

Comment: your route attribute value is same for both methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well make sure that you include the `{id}` token in your route definition:

```
[Route("api/users/{id}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSpecificUser(int id)
```